# Ruby timeout within a gets

Tags: ruby, timeout

I am trying to print `"Please input a value"` and raise a `Timeout::Error` if input is not received in 2 seconds.

I thought I could do:

```
puts "Please input a value"
Timeout.timeout(2) do
  ans = gets
end
raise "aborted" unless ans == 'y'
```

When I run the script, it prints the message, and then just sits. If I enter a value after 10 seconds (for example), then it times out. It doesn't hit the timeout until after I input a value.

Comment: It runs ok from console for me. maybe will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410527/ruby-timeout-not-timing-out

Comment: What version of ruby are you running? Any different if you do `Timeout::timeout(2)`?

Comment: @GregoryOstermayr That [wouldn't make a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11043499/3784008).

Comment: Try if `$stdin.gets` makes a difference. Also what OS is this? The code works fine for me.

Comment: this is running on windows 10 using ruby 2.4.3p205

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want just `y` answer and you want to give 2 seconds for answering.

You can use `begin..rescue..end` construction and cycle `until` for `y` answer

```
require 'timeout'

puts 'Input something'

begin
  status = Timeout::timeout(2) { answer = gets.chomp.downcase until answer == 'y' }
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts 'Time is out'
end
```

But in Windows it's better to use `STDIN.gets`. You can read about this [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6661)

Comment: I can confirm this works. No idea why it would be downvoted.

Comment: not sure what to tell you but I have tried this repeatedly and it flat does not work. So that is why I down voted it.

Comment: Did you try `STDIN.gets.chomp.downcase`? Did you read [this](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6661)?

Comment: [On Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10434188/3784008), consider wrapping the `gets` call in `Thread.new`, e.g., `Timeout.timeout(2) { Thread.new { gets.chomp.downcase }.join }`. This may work, it may not. Running Ruby on Windows is a crapshoot; if you have to use Windows, consider using [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) to skip past all these implementation quirks and workarounds.